# How do I attach a skirt with a cloth modifier to the cg cookie flex rig?

Tags: modeling, rigging, cloth-simulation

I have tried parenting the skirt to various parts of the armature and mesh, but this has not worked. I eventually want to animate this character and want the skirt to follow the moment of the hips. Thanks!

[Here is a link to the blender file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ums7dbfwb5sf7sy/CharacterTest_Skirt.blend?dl=0)

Note: if the rig does not appear, hit reload trusted in the top bar.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem, I needed to parent to bone instead of parent to object.